# How to graphs this gibbs fourier in matlab

Tags: matlab

please can somebody help me, I need to graph this wave closed teeth with gibbs oscillation, I have one day to do it and I never graph with Matlab.

This is the graph I try to programming for gibbs oscillation wave: http://imageshack.us/a/img585/9724/kakai12.jpg

This is what I've done but not really if it worked this way.

```
clear all; 
syms x n; 
f=(-4)*(x-pi); 
T=2; w0=((2*pi)/T); 
fb=f*sin(n*w0*x); 
bn=(2/x)*int(fb,x,0,2*pi); 
x=0:1/(1000):15; 
bn_12=bn*sin(n*w0*x); 
c=1; j=100; 
fs=symsum(bn_12,n,c,j)
```

Can somebody helpme please.

Answer (score 0):

Can't test this right now but something like this should work:

```
t = -4:0.01:4 %Create numerical vector of time
T = 2; %Period, adjust as suitable
V = 4; %Adjust to appropriate amplitude
w0 = 2*pi/T; %Angular frequency

line = (V/pi) * w0 * t - V; %Start with straight line with correct gradient and y intercept
%Then subtract 2*V for every 2*pi
step = floor((w0 * t) / (2*pi))*2*V; %So step should be a step function that steps up 2V every 2pi
sawtooth = line  - step;

plot(w0*t, sawtooth)
```

Comment: This is what he showed, 
http://imageshack.us/a/img855/2536/subvf.png
I have another question if I wanted to repeat the wave as in the graph repeats every 2pi, how to should be programmed in matlab?

Comment: Sorry the issue was a missing bracket in creating 'step'. I wanted to divide by 2 pi by was dividing by 2 then multiplying by pi. Try the edited version above, I tested it here: http://weboctave.mimuw.edu.pl/weboctave/web/index.php#menus  and it works. Hope this was on time for you.

Comment: @Dan Next time you can use Saturn Fiddles to run MATLAB/Octave code. Check out this plot at https://saturnapi.com/vpartition/closed-teeth-with-gibbs-fourier-oscillation